# Adding github token to git

Tags: git, github

How do I add a token from github to my git config files so I don't have to enter my username and password everytime I want to push my commits to my Github?

EDIT: 
I've done everything what those articles say: https://help.github.com/articles/generating-a-new-ssh-key-and-adding-it-to-the-ssh-agent/
https://help.github.com/articles/adding-a-new-ssh-key-to-your-github-account/

Got this particular SSH installed on my computer + it is added on github and when I try to `git push origin master` terminal asks me for username. Is there a way to fix that? I mean I want it to use my SSH key and bother me with logging everytime I push my commits.

Comment: https://help.github.com/articles/which-remote-url-should-i-use/#cloning-with-https-urls-recommended

Comment: So even if I want to use SSH I will still be prompted to enter my username? Is there a way to completely avoid that?

Comment: No, SSH identifies you by the used key. No need to enter any username with SSH.

Comment: No, SSH won't ask for it

Comment: Added edit explaining why it's not working for me.

Answer (score 1):

For the functionality you desire, the best way is to [connect with SSH](https://help.github.com/articles/connecting-to-github-with-ssh/).

At a high level, here are the steps:

1. Navigate to your .ssh directory:

> cd ~/.ssh

2. Generate your rsa keys:

> ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C "your_email@example.com"

3. Open the public key file

> vim rsa.pub

4. Copy the contents of this file, and paste it into your SSH Keys section on Github (click your icon in the upper right corner, then click -> Settings -> SSH & GPG keys -> New SSH Key).

[image]

---

If even after doing this the command line is still asking you to login when you push, try setting your git config globally:

> $ git config --global user.name "John Doe"
>
> $ git config --global user.email johndoe@example.com

Comment: @doublmc Please check my edit at the end here. Does that help you?